# Python: Is there a way to pretty-print a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My list produces the following output: (running Python 3.4)

```
('MSG1', 3030)
('MEMORYSPACE', 3039)
('NEWLINE', 3040)
('NEG48', 3041)
```

Is there any way to make all the numbers line up like a column? Thanks.
My code is a simple print statement:

```
for element in data:
    print (element)
```

Comment: look up [pprint](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html), standard pretty print module.

Comment: `pprint` won't d you any good for a nested iterable like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can justify according to the longest word:

```
longest = max([len(x[0]) for x in data])

for j in data:
    a = j[0].ljust(longest)
    b = str(j[1])
    print(' '.join([a, b]))
```

Here is the output:

```
MSG1        3030
MEMORYSPACE 3039
NEWLINE     3040
NEG48       3041
```

Comment: What version of Python are you running?

Comment: I am running version 3.4

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried [format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)?

```
max_len = max([len(x[0]) for x in data])

for element in data:
    print '{value0:{width0}} {value1}'.format(value0=element[0],
                                              width0=max_len,
                                              value1=element[1])
```

Sample output:

```
MSG1        3030
MEMORYSPACE 3039
NEWLINE     3040
NEG48       3041
```

---

You could also right-justify by adding `>` to the format specifier:

```
    ...
    print '{value0:>{width0}} {value1}'.format(
    ...
```

Produces:

```
       MSG1 3030
MEMORYSPACE 3039
    NEWLINE 3040
      NEG48 3041
```

Comment: I don't know the number of columns, that was just an example

Comment: You could compute the number of columns (as in the accepted answer) and then use `format`.

Comment: Answer updated to compute the number of columns.  Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `'\t'`:

```
for element in data:
    print str(element[0])+'\t'+str(element[1])
```

---

```
MSG1    3030
MEMORYSPACE 3039
NEWLINE 3040
NEG48   3041
```

Unfortunately, because your first elements are sometimes longer, try printing the number first:

```
for element in data:
    print str(element[1])+'\t'+str(element[0])
```

---

```
3030    MSG1
3039    MEMORYSPACE
3040    NEWLINE
3041    NEG48
```

Comment: i think op is running 3.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below. Since the second element is an integer value, you need to convert it into `string` type before printing.

```
>>> for x,y in data:
        print(x+"\t"+str(y))


MSG1    3030
MEMORYSPACE 3039
```

Comment: the one in infront of MEMORYSPACE does not line up

Comment: Not really pretty at all.

Answer (score 0):

I would print the number first, if possible:

```
for i in lst:
    print i[1],'\t',i[0]
```